# Why Does SerialPort's ReadByte Method Return an Int instead of a Byte?

Tags: c#, serial-port

It feels like an odd choice not to just return a byte. Is there a good reason for this? Also since this is not a byte can I just cast it to a byte to get the data?

Comment: end of the stream is represented by '-1' , There is not way you can represent invalid data. as the whole range of byte is valid.

Comment: That's the reason but one can still argue if its a good reason to signal end of stream. The are many other patterns to do it without mixing values and states. Like a TryReadByte with an out parameter or returning a tuple or throwning an exception or .... Presumably its just the way in the Framework because the WinAPI surfaces it that way and it was easiest to simply do alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it [needs to return -1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in case of end-of-stream:

> The byte, cast to an Int32, or -1 if the end of the stream has been read.

They could've used a smaller type, like a `short`/`int16`.